# How can I Delete data from Multiple tables with similar Table names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have 400+ tables named Test_1, Test_2..., Test_400

And I would like to empty those tables (not Drop).

Basically I would like to do a:

```
DELETE FROM Schema
WHERE Table_Name LIKE 'Test%'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you will need to dynamically generate a list of `delete` statements

Comment: Do any of these tables have any Foreign Key constraints?

Comment: Not sure if they have FK constraints.

Comment: Then find out... We can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming no foreign keys, this should do the trick.

There is obviously some danger in a script like this - I suggest a "dry run" where you just print out the statements, then uncomment the line that actually runs the deletes once you are happy.

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TEST%'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sql;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @sql;
    --UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE ONCE YOU ARE HAPPY ITS NOT GOING TO DELETE SOMETHING IT SHOULDN'T
    --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sql;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```